# Dragging images in table cell and keeping track of its location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have images in table cells that I would like drag. How can I modify the following so I can drag one image on top of another:

```
function drag(ob) {
ob.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ob.target.id); }

function drop(ob) {
var id = ob.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
if (!$(ob.currentTarget).find("img")[0])
    ob.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id));
ob.preventDefault();    
}

function allowDrop(ob) {
  ob.preventDefault();
}
```

complete code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/qgp7N/2/)

In addition, is it possible to have some code in the drop function that would display the file names of the of all the images (from row 1 to row 3) so I can pass it on to php for processing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. But this will allow images to drag over each other and removes the replaced image. There is also a small div that shows how to track image names.

I added a div to track names. You could easily make this a hidden field.

```
<div id="images"></div>
```

Then changed the drop to:

```
function drop(ob)
{
    var id = ob.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var t = ob.target;

    if (ob.target.nodeName == "IMG")
        t = ob.target.parentNode;

    t.innerHTML = "";
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    t.appendChild(img);

    $('#images').append(img.src + "; " )

    ob.preventDefault();    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qgp7N/3/

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. I am working on a chess game project where users will take turns. There will be no AI involved but I will be checking to see if a valid move was made. That is the reason I need to know where each piece is after each player moves. Do you think this is a proper way to approach it?

Comment: I would treat the board as an 8x8 array and then on every move, validate/update the array then bind the array to a UI. Lucky, a lot of people have made js chess games. Take a look at http://diovo.com/2011/12/chess-programming-in-javascript-part-1/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did do a lot research prior to posting here and even saw the link you suggested. Unfortunately, that link only goes through 2 lessons and does not explain what I am specifically looking for, -which is how to handle the user making a move.  Most of the coding would be done in php (which indeed I will use an array to store the board) I just don’t know how to handle the board display, javascript/jquery drag and drop and which piece was moved. The small board posted here was only to learn how to display the board. Any other tips/advice?

Comment: I did some more research; perhaps all I need is to know  from which cell the piece is being dragged from  and to which cell it is being dropped , i.e. R1C1-> R2C2 (as long as it is not being dragged and dropped to the same place).  Once a drag and drop is performed nothing else should be draggable.  I can perform all validation on the server side. I tried many times, with no success, to implement this with the current example. I am completely new to jquery, I am trying though.  What needs to be added/modified to the current code to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: When I was building my version of JS chess ( https://github.com/niyazpk/Chess.js ) , I was using jQuery UI DragDrop for this functionality and it worked just fine. The only thing that bugged me was that the validate property in the DragDrop options will not allow you to dynamically validate moves. For this you will have to validate your internal representation and then move display that board on screen.

Comment: The java chess game is very impressive Niyaz, way beyond me. All I want to do is know which cell the piece is coming from and where it is being placed.